# SQL query filter NULL and current month

Tags: sql

I have a SQL query and I would like it to list records that:

- Are in one of these IDProcessState(s): 5, 6 or 7
- If IDProcessState is 7, it should only show the ones that were submitted (DtSubmission) this month
- If IDProcessState is 5 or 6 it should still show the records (they have null DtSubmission column)

The code below shows records with current month submissions (IDProcessState = 7) but excludes the ones that were not yet submitted, and therefore, excludes the ones in IDProcessState 5 or 6 (in these states, the processes were not submitted yet).

```
SELECT        IDProcess, Fee, DtSubmission
FROM            dbo.Process
WHERE        (IDProcessState IN ('5', '6', '7')) AND (DtSubmission >= DATEADD(month, 
DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
```

I assume I should use something like "CASE WHEN" but I'm only getting syntax errors

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need to use CASE. `WHERE IDProcessState in (5,6) OR (IDProcessState == 7 AND submitted this month)`

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your syntax, this answer assumes you are using SQL Server.

In SQL Server, you can express this as:

```
WHERE IDProcessState IN (5, 6) OR
      (IDProcessState = 7 AND
       DATEDIFF(month, DtSubmission, GETDATE()) = 0
      )
```

Note that this assumes that `IDProcessState` is a number -- it looks like a number.

I might also suggest phrasing this as:

```
WHERE IDProcessState IN (5, 6, 7) AND
      (IDProcessState <> 7 OR
       DtSubmission >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()), MONTH(GETDATE()), 1) 
      )
```

This version assumes there are no future dates.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT        IDProcess, Fee, DtSubmission 
FROM          dbo.Process
WHERE        
(IDProcessState = '7' and month(DtSubmission ) = MONTH(getdate()))
or IDProcessState in ('5','6')
```

Comment: This seems to not take into consideration the year. but the logic works ("OR")

Answer (score 0):

You can get output by modify where condition only as -

```
SELECT        IDProcess, Fee, DtSubmission
FROM            dbo.Process
WHERE IDProcessState in (5,6) OR (IDProcessState == 7 AND MONTH(DtSubmission) = MONTH(getdate()))
```

I hope it will works for you.

Comment: You literally copied my comment without replacing the "submitted this month" :O If you post an answer make at least sure it has a valid syntax.